# How to combine Firebase Realtime database with RxJava

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rx-java

I'm trying to understand how I can combine both Firebase Realtime Database, which emits a stream of raw data (suppose, new users data - one by one), and RxJava which I designate to be the tool I use for handling the received data -  which should go through several filters, load images (that I want to be performed on different threads) and in the end will produce the complete data sample one by one (the order does not matter and a different samples of data can be processed in parallel if is it possible because data samples don't depend on each other).

Because I'm completely new to RxJava, I would love to get some examples or references.

Suppose this is the function through which I listen to Firebase and want to convert to use with RxJava as the processing pipeline the data passes through from Firebase to the liveData, and will help me with parallel computations, to do tasks on the right threads etc:

```
public void newUsers() {
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("Users");
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            User userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            
            myUserAddedListener = (user)-> {
                liveUserDataListener.onFinish(userData);
            };

            filterA(userData);
            filterB(userData); 
            loadImagesOnProperThreadWithRxJava(userData);
            doingSomeThings(userData);
            
            myUserAddedListener.onComplete(userData);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Another thing, the Firebase listener can produce new sample relativley fast, while the processing process of each sample can take a long time.  How can such a case be handled?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rx wrappers to integrate Firebase Realtime Database, Firebase Authentication, or any other Firebase service. Here are some examples:

*ShopService class:*

```
public class ShopService extends BaseService {

    @Inject
    public ShopService() {
    }

    public Observable<Shop> getShopsById(String id) {
        return observeSingleValueEvent(databaseReference
                .child("shops").child(id)).concatMap(dataSnapshot ->
                singleMapper(dataSnapshot)
                        .toObservable());

    }

    public Observable<List<Shop>> getShopsByUser(User user) {
        return observeValueEvent(databaseReference
                .child("shop_by_user")
                .child(user.getPhoneNumber()), BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
                .concatMap(this::mapper)
                .toObservable();
    }

    private Flowable<List<Shop>> mapper(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        return Flowable.fromCallable(() -> {
            List<Shop> elements = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ShopDTO shopDTO = itemSnapshot.getValue(ShopDTO.class);
                if (shopDTO != null) {
                    shopDTO.setId(itemSnapshot.getKey());
                    Shop shop = ShopDTOMapper.map(shopDTO);
                    elements.add(shop);
                }
            }
            return elements;
        });
    }

    private Flowable<Shop> singleMapper(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        return Flowable.fromCallable(() -> {
            Shop shop = null;
            ShopDTO shopDTO = dataSnapshot.getValue(ShopDTO.class);
            if (shopDTO != null) {
                shop = ShopDTOMapper.map(shopDTO);
            }
            return shop;
        });
    }
}
```

*BaseService class*:

```
class BaseService {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    BaseService() {

        if (databaseReference == null) {
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    Observable<DataSnapshot> observeSingleValueEvent(@NonNull final Query query) {
        return Observable.create(emitter ->
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            emitter.onNext(dataSnapshot);
                        } else {
                            emitter.onComplete();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        if (!emitter.isDisposed())
                            emitter.onError(error.toException());
                    }
                }));
    }

    @NonNull
    Flowable<DataSnapshot> observeValueEvent(@NonNull final Query query,
                                             @NonNull BackpressureStrategy strategy) {
        return Flowable.create(emitter -> {
            final ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    emitter.onNext(dataSnapshot);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull final DatabaseError error) {
                    if (!emitter.isCancelled())
                        emitter.onError(error.toException());
                }
            };
            emitter.setCancellable(() -> query.removeEventListener(valueEventListener));

            query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
        }, strategy);
    }
}
```

Also, I recommend you this article to: https://yaircarreno.medium.com/rx-wrappers-to-integrate-firebase-authentication-8e3fe2c52dc4

Also, **Flowable** can help you with overflooded scenarios that require *backpressure strategies*.